# call twitter api for checking username

Tags: javascript, twitter

Since my script is running on a different domain from twitter and since I'm using ajax to call the next url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name="+screenName, I must set the datatype to "jsonp".

The problem is that according to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request, you must set the HTTP headers with oauth details and you can't set headers for the http call when using setting datatype "jsonp".

You can call the above url for checking screen names but it has a rate limit and I want to increase the limit by using a twitter application I've created.

How can it be done ?